# How do I change cell values by selecting on another cell using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to using Google App Script and I am trying to apply it to my Google Sheets. I am trying to make the selected cell change another cell's value (E2) to the one that is selected. There is a range of cells with different values (E2:G20). I want to be able to click on any of the cell within the range and have it change E2. Here is my code (this is what I have so far):

```
  function updateValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet9")
  const namedRangesL = ss.getRangeByName("mzLeft")
  const namedRangesR = ss.getRangeByName("mzRight")
  const mzdropdown = datasheet.getRange("E2")

// Selecting Cells
  const selection = ss.getSelection();
  const CurrentCell1 = selection.getCurrentCell();
 
// Current Cell: Action
  CurrentCell1.getValues.namedRangesL();
  CurrentCell1.setValue().mzdropdown
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your question and `const namedRangesL = ss.getRangeByName("mzLeft")` and `const namedRangesR = ss.getRangeByName("mzRight")` and `const mzdropdown = datasheet.getRange("E2")`? And about `const mzdropdown = datasheet.getRange("E2")`, from the variable name, is this a dropdown list?

Comment: Both mzLeft/Right are the named ranges from two different data. Mzleft is E2:G20, I only listed one of the ranges since I want to figure out how to get it to work first.

Comment: and yes, E2 is a dropdown list that is uses Data Validation. Essentially, I wanted to click on the named range cells which will change the value within the Data Validation cell to output data that I've linked to that string.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Essentially, I wanted to click on the named range cells which will change the value within the Data Validation cell to output data that I've linked to that string.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes,  for example, one cell within the named range has a string value "MZ1-0-A". If I click on this cell, I also want my E2 cell (drop-down) to have the same string value as the cell that I just clicked/selected on. 

I am using the query formula to show all the data associated with "MZ1-0-A"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am using the query formula to show all the data associated with "MZ1-0-A"`, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I made the query to show 3 columns which includes the name, location, and quantity since it'll be used for inventory.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really doing anything but this is how it should be written

```
function updateValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet9")
  const rg1 = ss.getRangeByName("mzLeft")
  const rg2 = ss.getRangeByName("mzRight")
  const sh1E2 = sh1.getRange("E2")

// Selecting Cells
 
  const CurrentCell1 = sh.getCurrentCell();
  CurrentCell1.getValue();
  CurrentCell1.setValue()
```